# Proving that Set O is the smallest set satisfying these properties

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

$O_n$ is defined as: $O_n = {1}$; $O_{n+1} = O_n \cup \{2n+1\}$. Let $O = \cup_n O_n $

Prove that $O$ is the smallest set satisfying properties O1 and O2.

O1: $1 \in O$

O2: if $x \in O$ then $x+2 \in O$

---

Let S be a set which satisfies properties, O1 and O2.
Now Let $y \in O$. 
Then, $y \in \cup_n O_n $ and $y$ some odd integer number. 
Since we know that $S$ is a set of all odd nonnegative integers by its properties (i.e. if 1 is in $S$, then 3 is, and 5, so on), it follows that $y \in S$ and this can be shown for all $y \in O$.

Thus, $O \subseteq S$ and $O$ is the smallest set satisfying properties O1 and O2.

Is this fine?

Comment: yea edited y, its some odd number

Comment: @Jay y isn't a set of odd numbers, it's a single odd number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be very rigorous: let $S$ satisfy O1 and O2. Then, by induction, we see that $S$ must contain all the odd natural numbers. Let $y \in \cup_n O_n$. Then there exists some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$y \in O_n = O_{n-1} \cup \{2n - 1\} = O_{n-2} \cup \{ 2n - 3 \} \cup \{2n - 1\} = \cdots = \cup_{i=1}^n \{2n - (2i-1)\}.$$

(To be very rigorous about the dots, one may use induction again.) Thus $y = 2n - (2i - 1) = 2(n-i) + 1$ for some $1 \leq i \leq n$, i.e., $y$ is some odd natural number. Hence $y \in S$ as required.